# Jquery change event not working in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

hey guys I have just try to implement my change event in coffeescript but its not working. Will any help me

```
$('#subscription_id").on "change", -> 
console.log "Hello"
outputs = $(this).val()

if outputs
 $('#subscription_id').prop "disable", "false"
else
 $('##subscription_id').prop "disable", "true"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The colors indicate the problem :

```
$('#subscription_id").on "change"
```

Should probably be

```
$('#subscription_id').on "change"
```